# Cascading Dropdown for Lookup with more than 20 items

Tags: lookup-column, spservices, cascading

I have implemented cascading dropdown using SPCascadingDropdown (SPServices) it was working for lookup with 19 items . When the items count became more than 20 , the lookup column is displayed as input and required doubleclick to select the item. So i changed that complex control to simple dropdown using the solution provided in this link...http://sharepointegg.blogspot.in/2010/10/fixing-sharepoint-2010-lookup-drop-down.html..But cascading dropdown stopped working ... tried the SPCascadingDropdownEx given in the same url but it is not working for me . Please somebody help me

Note : Also tried SPComplextoSimpledropdown but i am facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

SPServices will convert the dropdown to a simple select for you; it's one of the options. Simply set `simpleChild: true`. If you used SPComplextoSimpledropdown properly, then the cascading should have worked, but the option is built into SPCasecadeDropdowns so there's no need to call it separately.

The reason that the cascading stopped working when you used the other solution is that it changed the DOM in a way that SPCascadeDropdowns didn't understand.

Comment: What happens when I have parent and child columns 20+ items? I mean, this works (simpleChild: true) if parent column has less than 20 items. If parent column has more than 19 items than I can't make it work as it shows only promptText if it is set or just None if nothing is set for promptText.

Comment: If you're using version 2014.02, it should handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can by using SPServices, for full tutorial please visit http://sharepointkids.blogspot.in/2014/04/two-level-cascading-drop-down-in.html