# Cascading Dropdown for Lookup with more than N items

Tags: spservices

I've got cascading dropdowns implemented for sharepoint 2007. It worked fine until lists exceeded 100 items.

My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Service",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Applications",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Application",
        childColumn: "Service",
        simpleChild: true,
        debug: true
    });
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Area",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Applications",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Application",
        childColumn: "Area",
        simpleChild: true,
        debug: true
    });                                
});
```

My Area and Service stop  populating automatically after I've added 100+ item to the aplication. What was strange is that it's working under FF and Chrome but not for IE. I found the solution in this post: [Cascading Dropdown for Lookup with more than 20 items](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41524/cascading-dropdown-for-lookup-with-more-than-20-items). I've added to above code `simpleChild: true`, bit and it started to work.

Well... it's not exactly working. After I choose Application my area and service gets populated BUT in the application dropdown I still need to double click my choice to populate other dropdowns. And still it only works that way in IE. In FF and Chrome its fine.

Any ideas why?

Thanks
E

Answer (score 2):

Found description of my problem here :
http://sympmarc.com/2010/05/19/two-types-of-sharepoint-forms-dropdowns/
and the solution is here:
http://sympmarc.com/2011/05/09/new-spservices-function-spcomplextosimpledropdown/

so end up with my code looks like this:

```
    $().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown({
        columnName: "Application",
        completefunc: null,
        debug: true
    });
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Service",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Applications",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Application",
        childColumn: "Service",
        simpleChild: true,
        debug: true
    });
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Area",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Applications",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Application",
        childColumn: "Area",
        simpleChild: true,
        debug: true
    });
```

And all works well.
Hope this helps anyone.

Regards 
E